# checkedlistbox operation in c#

Tags: c#, .net, checkedlistbox

I am developing a C# application in which a CheckedListBox is used.

The CheckedListBox contains subject names like: Accounting, OC, Physics, Economics, Maths, etc...

I have one database table in which fees are associated with particular subjects:

Eg table name Fee:

```
Subject      |     Fee

Accounting         2000
Economics          3000
OC                 2000
```

I want to build the application such that when a user clicks on a subject in the CheckedListBox, it's fees should automatically be added to a total.

For that I have tried different CheckedListBox events: `Click`, `SelectedIndexChanged`, `ItemCheck`, etc...

But I am not getting the correct behavior when I make the first check on the CheckedListBox.

For the testing I have added the following subjects to the CheckedListBox: Accounting, Economics and Maths.

And this is what I have in my event handler:

```
for(int i=0; i<chlstbox.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
    messagebox.show(chklstbox.CheckedItems[i].ToString());
}
```

When I check the first subject Accounting then it does not shows me any message box. But when I click on Economics it shows me Accounts and then Economics.

In this case it should show me Accounting when i first click on Accounting. And there is no reply when I un-check the subjects.

What should I do? Is there any particular event or technique associated with it which I should use?

Comment: post your event handler code.

Comment: sir, event handler code is that for loop code which i have written in post

Comment: that's not valid syntax, so i figured you are not showing the entire function.

Comment: Yeah.just a minute. I will edit my post

Comment: is it ok now? or should i add something more?

Comment: and have you only subscribed to the `ItemCheck` event?  because you should only need to subscribe to that event and not all 3 that you mentioned.

Comment: no. i have tried with all the three at different times. i have used it one at a time. but no one has gave me desired output

Comment: If you have ItemDatabound event or SelectedIndexChanged event then add your login in those methods.

Comment: when i makes first item checked in this event then i do not gets the result.but as soon as i checks second item also i gets the result of both the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [ItemChecketEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt06shbb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you will see the CurrentValue, OldValue and Index of the Item that is being Selected. So try something like this. The [ItemCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Event lets you know what is changing before it physically is changed.

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. Worked Perfectly. Again Thanks a lot...also learnt a new thing today